# Average all PingReply RoundTripTime in array C# WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, ping, long-integer

I'm working on a new program in C# WPF, and part of it includes averaging ten `PingReply.RoundTripTime` and dividing it by two to find the one-way trip time. I put all the `PingReply` instances in an array, `arrayReply`, and now want to perform the above operations. I've tried a bunch of things, but this is what I have right now:

```
//New integer replyCount for counting ping replies
int replyCount = 0;
long Atime = 0;
long time = 0;

//for each PingReply instance in arrayReply
foreach (PingReply r in arrayReply)
{
    //set long integer (64-bit) Atime (time of ping) to the previous value of Atime
    //plus half of the next RoundTripTime divided by 2 (for approx one-way distance)
    long oneWayTime = r.RoundtripTime / 2;

    long x = Atime + oneWayTime;

    //add one to replyCount
    replyCount++;

    //Divide Atime by number of replies
    time = x / replyCount;
}

pingAverage.Text = time.ToString();
```

However, this results in 0 every time. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using ping on the same computer the time will be very small so zero is normal.  Try a remote PC.

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through and examine the variable values. When one comes up different than you expected, figure out why. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It looks like you never assign a value to `Atime` except during initialization, so it's always going to be 0.

Comment: Also, you've fallen into the bad commenting trap. `replyCount++` does not deserve a comment. And your next comment isn't even incorrect.

Comment: Having `time` be an integer data type (`long`) is not a good idea when trying to compute an average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ to average:

```
var time = arrayReply.Average(pr => pr.RoundtripTime) / 2;
```